# Stop form action redirect or href redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect, shopify

Please help. I'm trying to integrate shopifys shopping cart outside of shopify itself. Basically I need to submit a form and keep it from redirecting so I can allow the customer to add all the items he wants before proceeding to checkout instead of one.

I've been trying two methods:

First method using just a link:

```
<a href="http://statevintage.myshopify.com/cart/add" onclick="var f = document.createElement('form'); f.style.display = 'none'; this.parentNode.appendChild(f); f.method = 'POST'; f.action = this.href; var v = document.createElement('input'); v.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); v.setAttribute('name', 'id'); v.setAttribute('value', '281514140'); f.appendChild(v); var r = document.createElement('input'); r.setAttribute('type', 'hidden'); r.setAttribute('name', 'return_to'); r.setAttribute('value', 'back'); f.appendChild(r); f.submit(); return false;">BUY NOW</a>
```

Second method using form submission with return_to:

```
<form action="http://statevintage.myshopify.com/cart/add" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="281514140" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="back" />
<input type="submit" value="BUY NOW" />
</form>
```

No matter what I do even using a return false script I still get sent to checkout!

This guy is using the same form functionality, just with quantity options, http://sageinvoices.co.uk/ but for some reason it never leaves his site until you actually checkout. Which should be because of

```
 <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="back" />
```

I've followed every wiki I can find and I just can not stop the form redirect to my checkout page. I plan on producing a cart count and item display then allowing the user to checkout when they want. Also I can not change platforms for my client! It has to work for shopify. Also I can not use their app or iframe method. This site must be cross browser compatible and fast.

Comment: You say you need it to work outside of shopify, but your two examples explicitly point to the myshopify.com domain. If you want it to work on your site, you'll need to write some code to handle the actions of shopify - just as your example site (sageinvoices.co.uk) does.

Comment: Yes they do point that way. So does his site technically. As well as this one http://11heavens.com/testing-shopify-add-to-cart-functionality-from-another-website-while-staying-put#add-to-cart-form

I've done a whois and he has merely changed the dns...which I can do as well to statevintage.com. Shopify offers this within its settings. I have tried with both urls already. It did nothing different. Checkout the other link above, the url is theirshop.myshopify.com and it works fine!

I do not want to use or create a shopify theme when there is no need! He uses the site for tracking purposes.

Comment: If you actually take the time to add it to the cart then checkout from  http://sageinvoices.co.uk you will see it directs to shopify not his own checkout merely one step later. He has merely masked the url. That it what I'm trying to make happen. Then I'll use a frame to display cart quantity, which I have already successfully taken care of. The form does add the item to my cart. I just can not stop the redirect. I want the user to be able to checkout when they deem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you `f.submit()` the form, it does what it says: submit the form ;-)

It is possible to prevent the default submit behaviour, for example using jQuery:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Still redirects using the code above. That's what is confusing me is I've tried... f.submit(); return false;"> in numerous methods. Any other thoughts.

Comment: At www.jsfiddle.net I get valid code but I'm seeing {"error": "Please use POST request"} Also I'm not getting redirected there.